# React: Post ManyToMany Field to API

Tags: reactjs, api

i have a form that contains an option for Tags and to be able to pick multiple tags for one item i made it a manytomany field but i do not know how to post it this is what i did

```
this.state = {
title:'',
Tag:[],
};

handleTag(value) {
    this.setState({
        Tag: value,
    }); 
}

handleSubmit (values) {
let form_data = new FormData();
form_data.append('title',values.title);
form_data.append('Tag',this.state.Tag);
axios({
    method: "post",
    url: "/API/Create_item",
    data: form_data,
    headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
  })
```

when i console.log Tag after selecting more then one Tag (it works when i only select one) i get an array like this ["1","2"] but i get an error saying "Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received str."

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out

```
handleSubmit (values) {
let form_data = new FormData();
form_data.append('title',values.title);

for (let i=0; i<=this.state.Lab.length-1; i++) {
    form_data.append('Label',this.state.Lab[i]);
}

axios({
    method: "post",
    url: "/API/Create_item",
    data: form_data,
    headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
  })
}
```